# Special Characters Restriction Rule in XSD

Tags: xsd

restrict special characters in my XSD validation , i am able to handle , some characters with this pattern    **"([a-zA-Z0-9_.' !@#$%^*()_+={}|/:;,>?/`~ ])+"**

but not able to handle below :

"
&
'
<
\
®
™

any ideas ?

also not able to handle them with [^] pattern

Answer (score 6):

You want define a type that extends string and add a restriction with a pattern
Something like

```
<xs:element name="your_element">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9_.' !@#$%^*()_+={}|/:;,>?/`~ ]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can add the escape character \ (backslash) before any special character you want to add to the pattern. For example:

```
<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z 0-9_.,()/=!\[\]&quot;#%&amp;*;&lt;&gt;&apos;+:?-]"/>
```

where you see the square brackets [ and ] included in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use character entities. `&amp;` for the ampersand, for example, and `&lt;` for the less. XML Schema is XML, and you have to live with XML rules. Expanding your question to actually show us the schema context would help.

Comment: ok , thnx ,i am able to handle them still no luck to allow characters ® ™

Comment: You'll need to use # escape codes for these two characters, so &#x2122; for TM and &#x00ae; for (R).